# AsyncTask to get Location in android go wrong with "can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()"

Tags: android, gps

all

I have carefully read many related Q&A in this site, but nothing help me. Here is my code, it works fine with GPS on, but went wrong once i turn off the GPS.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author Jimmy Chiang
 * 
 */
public class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Location> {

    private OnLocationListener[] mGpsListeners;
    private Location location;

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location lo) {
            location = lo;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public interface OnLocationListener {
        public void onLocationGot(Location location);
    }

    public GetLocationTask setOnLocationListener(
            OnLocationListener... listeners) {
        mGpsListeners = listeners;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Location doInBackground(Context... params) {


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) params[0]
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

        }
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        while (location == null) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1,locationListener);
        }
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {

        for (OnLocationListener listener : mGpsListeners) {
            listener.onLocationGot(location);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception shows:

> can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   looper.prepare()

Some posts show that the problem should be call someting in UI Thread, but i can't find any of this. Thanks so much if you know what's going on~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1,locationListener);
```

with

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1,locationListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

as stand in the docs

```
Looper.getMainLooper()
```

> Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread
>   of the
>   application.

the looper arguments of requestLocationUpdate is a Looper object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread.

If you want the AsyncTask to be the one that will receive the messages you have to use

```
  Looper.myLooper().prepare();
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1,locationListener, Looper.myLooper());
```

Comment: but Looper.prepare() returns void, so the last line is wrong?